# How to get the BlockNumber property and object contents in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, web3py

I'm trying to get the `blockNumber` connected to my URL Infura. But I get a property and cannot see what is in the object.

```
from web3 import Web3
import web3

infura_url = 'myUrl'

w = Web3(Web3.HTTPProvider(infura_url))

print(w.isConnected())
print(web3.eth.Eth.blockNumber)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work for you:

```
from web3 import Web3

infura_url = "https://mainnet.infura.io/v3/YOUR_INFURA_PROJECT_ID"
web3 = Web3(Web3.HTTPProvider(infura_url))

print(web3.isConnected())
print(web3.eth.blockNumber)
```

Comment: It was coming from the variable 'w' that I had to use with the method 'eth.Eht'

Comment: Also `eth.Eth`. You just need `eth`.